# IndexError: string index out of range when reading CSV

Tags: python-3.x, index-error

I'm very new to programming and have been piecing together some programs from some very helpful threads, but I'm a bit stuck here. First post so sorry if I'm an idiot. I've seen posts on this topic but I'm not sure how the answers apply to my situation. I'm getting the error below:

> File "C:/Users/david/rest sand.py", line 33, in 
>     portfolio.append(row[2])
>   IndexError: string index out of range

Here is what I have:

```
import csv
with open('C:/Users/david/OneDrive/Desktop/CSV/Extracted/ENV EXPORT TEST.csv', 'r') as lookuplist:
with open('C:/Users/david/OneDrive/Desktop/CSV/Extracted/RESTRICTION TEST.csv', 'r') as csvinput:
    with open('C:/Users/david/OneDrive/Desktop/CSV/combined.csv', 'w') as output:
        export = csv.reader(lookuplist)
        restrictions = csv.reader(csvinput)
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        d = {}
        for ac in restrictions:
            d[ac[0]] = ac[3:]
        for i in export:
            if i[0] in d:
                i.append(d[i[0]])
            writer.writerow(i)

account = []
portfolio = []
MKT_val = []
closed = []
restriction = []

with open('C:/Users/david/OneDrive/Desktop/CSV/combined.csv') as combinedCSV:
    csvReader = csv.reader(combinedCSV)
    for row in combinedCSV:
        account.append(row[0])
        portfolio.append(row[1])
        MKT_val.append(row[2])
        closed.append(row[3])
        restriction.append(row[4])

for a, b, c, d, e in zip(account,portfolio,MKT_val,closed,restriction):
    while e.startswith('[A1]'):
        print(a,b,c,d,e)
```

The writer CSV comes out like:

```
Account    Portfolio    Mkt Value   Closed  ['Restriction']

362301370   CIG       24154         YES     ['A1']

917367810   MGI       16509         NO      ['B2']

948462741   FG        26626         YES     ['C3']
```

What I'm looking for is to just have the first row of the CSV print to the console.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: try `for row in csvReader`

Comment: Thanks for your response, Akshay! Should have caught that. Unfortunately I'm now I'm getting "IndexError: list index out of range" and it references line 32 instead of 33. Any thoughts?

Comment: it's really hard to tell unless you provide full traceback